# Finding the distance which a parametric curve has moved away from the tangent to a point $\gamma(t)$ in during $\delta t$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, solution-verification, curves

Andrey Pressley states in his book *Elementary Differential Geometry* (pp. 29) that

> Suppose that $\gamma$ is a unit-speed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$. As the parameter $t$ of $\gamma$ changes to $t + \delta t$, the curve moves away from its tangent line at $\gamma(t)$ by a distance $(\gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t))\cdot \mathbb{n}$, where $\mathbb{n}$ is the unit vector perpendicular to the tangent vector $\dot{\gamma}(t)$ of $\gamma$ at the point $\gamma(t)$

The author does not provide any intermediary steps for this conclusion. My question is is that why does the following interpretation lead to the same result: As we are interested in the deviation from the tangent $\dot{\gamma}(t)$, we can simply i.) project the normal vector onto the different vector $\gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t)$, ii.) find its norm. Combining these two steps gives $d = \left|\left|\mathrm{proj}_{\gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t)}(\mathbb{n})\right|\right| = \left|\left|(\gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t))(\frac{<\gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t), n>}{\left|\left|\gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t)\right|\right|\left|\left|\mathbb{n}\right|\right|})\right|\right| = \left|\left|<\gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t), n>)\right|\right| = (\gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t))\cdot \mathbb{n}$

I am confused by this interpretation as to me it would make more sense to project the difference vector $\gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t)$ onto the *normal* vector, rather than the other way around, as we'd like to know how much we have moved away from the tangent.

Comment: Review how to find (using projection) the distance from a point in the plane to a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for the orthogonal projection is wrong. The orthogonal projection of a vector $v$ onto a vector $w$ is $P_wv = (v, \frac{w}{\lVert w \rVert})\frac{w}{\lVert w \rVert} = \frac{1}{\lVert w \rVert^2}(v, w)$.

It's not clear what the author is saying. Let $x$ be the closest vector in $\gamma(t) + \text{span}(\gamma'(t))$ to $\gamma(t + \delta t)$. He might mean that
$$\lVert \gamma(t + \delta t) - x \rVert = |(\gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t)) \cdot n|.$$
We have
$$\gamma(t + \delta t) - x= \gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t) - v,$$
where $v$ is the closest vector in $\text{span}(\gamma'(t))$ to $\gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t)$. From linear algebra, we know that $v$ is the orthogonal projection of $\gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t)$ onto $\text{span}(\gamma'(t))$. Therefore $\gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t)  - v$ is the orthogonal projection of $\gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t)$ onto $\text{span}(\gamma'(t))^{\perp} = \text{span}(n)$, so $\gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t)  - v = (\gamma(t + \delta t) - \gamma(t)) \cdot n$.